# Square Connect API : Partial Refund with same tender type

Tags: square-connect

I am using Square Connect API for refund and SDK in my iOS app for card payments only. Currently I am doing full refund of a transaction amount by creating refund end point.

Now, I want to make Partial Refund of the payment. Say, refund $50 from $100 of the payment/transaction.

Doc says :

> If you're creating a PARTIAL refund for a split tender payment,
>   instead provide the id of the particular tender you want to refund.

I am not using split tender. I have only Card type tender.

So, is this possible to make Partial Refund of same tender type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just specify the amount that you want to refund and provide the tender type for the card. See [Create Refund](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-createrefund)

Comment: Great ! I was thinking the same but had a doubt about it.